# How can I position CSS background-images within <li> links?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a navigation for a website using left floating unordered lists and am looking for a way to position an image underneath the currently active page link. I assume this can somehow be done with the CSS background-image property.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best way to do this is to set a `class` equal to `active` on the active link. This could be hard-coded in, or dynamically added using server-side code.

The HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li>Link</li>
   <li class="active">Link</li>
   <li>Link</li>
   <li>Link</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#nav .active {
   background-image:url('YourImage.png');
   background-position:50% 50%; /*Adjust as needed. Also accepts pixel values.*/
}
```

`Background-position` added on Godwin's suggestion. See [this link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position) for details on its use.

Comment: You can position the image below by setting the 'background-position' property. (by the way, 'background-image' is spelled incorrectly).

Comment: Thanks for the catch, and the extra details!